# SIM800: AT-command to get connected sender ids

Tags: arduino, gsm, sim, mobile-phones

I want to roughly estimate where my Arduino currently is. For this, I want to fetch the identification numbers of the stations it is currently connected to, so I can put them into an API which then gives me an estimation based on the phone masts. Sadly I haven't found anything regarding that topic in the datasheet.
 Do you know how I can ask for that info? Furthermore I'm currently looking for some database with all the mast coordinates, if you have any recommendations I would be very thankful for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you are looking for is [AT+CNETSCAN](https://www.elecrow.com/wiki/images/2/20/SIM800_Series_AT_Command_Manual_V1.09.pdf)  See page 197

The datasheet only shows a few of the commands.  The link I gave leads to a complete set of all AT commands for the SIM800.

Excerpt for AT+CNETSCAN:

[image]

Note that it tells you the country code, the operator code, and a cell ID code.

You will have to find a database somewhere inorder to resolve that information into a location.

I expect the cell IDs to be country dependent, and probably operator dependant as well.  That means you'd need to get that information from the company that operates a particular cell.

I found this [site](https://cell-id.info/) which will accept the given information and return a location.  I don't know if they have an API you could access in an automated way.

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed answer :) I apprechiate it

Comment: Edit: cell-id.info just sends the data you gave them to a php script via ajax, so by using JSONP it should be prety easy making an API out of it. Just search for the getData() function